# Getting a TypeError when trying to increase speed of animation using tkinter

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, methods, typeerror

I am trying to complete this homework assignment from Introduction to programming using Python.
It wants me to be able to use the up and down keys to increase and decrease speeds respectively. I have the start of the car(I still need to finish the shape), and I have a button to start and stop the car which work fine. However, when I try to run it using the example from the book(increaseSpeed and decreaseSpeed functions), it gives me "TypeError: increaseSpeed() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". I am not sure how to correct this in my code and it is beginning to frustrate me. The book doesn't even tell you why it used the sleepTime for increasing the speed of the message it originally used for the example.

```
from tkinter import *


class controlAnimation:
  def __init__(self):
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Racing Car")


    self.width = 250
    self.height = 100
    self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg="white", width=self.width, height=self.height)
    self.canvas.pack()
    frame = Frame(window)
    frame.pack()
    btStop = Button(frame, text = "Stop", command = self.stop)
    btStop.pack(side=LEFT)
    btStart = Button(frame, text = "Start", command = self.start)
    btStart.pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.x=0

    self.sleepTime = 100
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x,90,self.x+60,80,fill="black", tags = "car")
    self.canvas.create_oval(self.x+10, 90, self.x+20, 100, fill = "black",tags = "car")

    self.dx=3
    self.isStopped = False
    self.animate()



    window.bind("<Up>", self.increaseSpeed)
    window.bind("<Down>", self.decreaseSpeed)
    window.mainloop()
  def stop(self):
    self.isStopped = True
  def start(self):
    self.isStopped = False
    self.animate()
  def increaseSpeed(self):
    if self.sleepTime>5:
    self.sleepTime-=20
  def decreaseSpeed(self):
    self.sleepTime+=20

  def animate(self): # Move the message 
     while not self.isStopped:
      self.canvas.move("car", self.dx,0) 
      self.canvas.after(self.sleepTime) 
      self.canvas.update() 
      if self.x < self.width:
          self.x += self.dx 
      else:
        self.x = 0 

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x-60,90,self.x,80,fill="black", tags = "car")
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.x-50, 90, self.x-40, 100, fill = "black",tags = "car")
controlAnimation()
```

Comment: `.bind` function returns event, so what You can do is just add another argument to the `increaseSpeed` and `decreaseSpeed` functions, for example like this `increaseSpeed(self, event=None)` and `decreaseSpeed(self, event=None)` or without the `None` part (I don't think it was necessary to set to None) so like this maybe more compact: `increaseSpeed(self, event)`. You don't have to use that argument in the function

Comment: I also suggest following PEP 8 and using `snake_case` for variable and function names and `CapitalCase` for class names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.bind()` method returns an event and passes it to the given function.

Have a look here :

```py
def increaseSpeed(self):
    if self.sleepTime>5:self.sleepTime-=20
def decreaseSpeed(self):
    self.sleepTime+=20
```

Both these function don't take any arguments and so you see an error

So you need to do something like this :

```py
def increaseSpeed(self,event = None): #or def increaseSpeed(self,*args):
    #[...]
def decreaseSpeed(self,event = None): #or def decreaseSpeed(self,*args):
    #[...]
```

Here's the final working code -

```py
from tkinter import *


class controlAnimation:
  def __init__(self):
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Racing Car")


    self.width = 250
    self.height = 100
    self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg="white", width=self.width, height=self.height)
    self.canvas.pack()
    frame = Frame(window)
    frame.pack()
    btStop = Button(frame, text = "Stop", command = self.stop)
    btStop.pack(side=LEFT)
    btStart = Button(frame, text = "Start", command = self.start)
    btStart.pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.x=0

    self.sleepTime = 100
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x,90,self.x+60,80,fill="black", tags = "car")
    self.canvas.create_oval(self.x+10, 90, self.x+20, 100, fill = "black",tags = "car")

    self.dx=3
    self.isStopped = False
    self.animate()



    window.bind("<Up>", self.increaseSpeed)
    window.bind("<Down>", self.decreaseSpeed)
    window.mainloop()
  def stop(self):
    self.isStopped = True
  def start(self):
    self.isStopped = False
    self.animate()
  def increaseSpeed(self,event = None): #or def increaseSpeed(self,*args):
    if self.sleepTime>5:self.sleepTime-=20
  def decreaseSpeed(self,event = None): #or def increaseSpeed(self,*args):
    self.sleepTime+=20

  def animate(self): # Move the message 
     while not self.isStopped:
      self.canvas.move("car", self.dx,0) 
      self.canvas.after(self.sleepTime) 
      self.canvas.update() 
      if self.x < self.width:
          self.x += self.dx 
      else:
        self.x = 0 

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x-60,90,self.x,80,fill="black", tags = "car")
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.x-50, 90, self.x-40, 100, fill = "black",tags = "car")
controlAnimation()
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `widget.bind("<Event>", func)` the function passes an extra event to the function and you can use it if you like but apparently you don't need it so you can replace your binds in **init** with this:

```
    # You can either get the event using lambda if you don't want anything to do with it like this:
    window.bind("<Up>", lambda event: self.increaseSpeed)
    window.bind("<Down>", lambda event2: self.decreaseSpeed)
```

Or in your functions do this:

```
# Or you can pass it as an argument in your function
def increaseSpeed(self, event):
    if self.sleepTime > 5:
        self.sleepTime -= 20

def decreaseSpeed(self, event):
    self.sleepTime += 20
```

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
from tkinter import *


class CarAnimation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas_width = 550
        self.canvas_height = 280
        self.car_body_width = 100
        self.car_body_height = 50
        self.car_wheel_width = 20
        self.car_wheel_height = 20
        self.car_top_left = 0
        self.move_by = 1
        self.delay = 20
        self.default_delay = 10
        self.car_is_moving = False
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.title("Car Animation!")
        self.car_canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=self.canvas_width, height=self.canvas_height, background="white",
                                 highlightthickness=0)
        # If you have more shapes in the canvas that you do not want to get affected by the movement store them as
        # below and call the move function for each of them, I just stored them in a variable for demonstration purposes
        self.car_body = self.car_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.car_body_width, self.car_body_height)
        self.car_wheel1 = self.car_canvas.create_oval(0, self.car_body_height, self.car_wheel_width,
                                                      self.car_body_height+self.car_wheel_height)
        self.car_wheel2 = self.car_canvas.create_oval(self.car_body_width-self.car_wheel_width, self.car_body_height,
                                                      self.car_body_width, self.car_body_height+self.car_wheel_height)
        self.start_btn = Button(self.root, text="Start Car", command=self.start_car)
        self.stop_btn = Button(self.root, text="Stop Car", command=self.stop_car)
        self.car_canvas.pack(side=TOP)
        self.start_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=5)
        self.stop_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.root.bind("<Up>", self.decrease_delay)
        self.root.bind("<Down>", self.increase_delay)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_car(self):
        if not self.car_is_moving:
            self.car_is_moving = True
            self.move_car()

    def stop_car(self):
        if self.car_is_moving:
            self.car_is_moving = False

    def move_car(self):
        # Instead of storing the car's top left position and appending to it, you can also
        # 'self.car_canvas.coords(self.car_body)[0]' so that it would return the shape's coords
        if self.car_is_moving and self.car_top_left < self.canvas_width:
            self.car_top_left += self.move_by
            # You can store their layer numbers and move them one by one but since there were no more shapes
            # I decided to move all of them at once using 'ALL'
            self.car_canvas.move(ALL, self.move_by, 0)
            self.root.after(self.delay, self.move_car)
        elif self.car_is_moving and self.car_top_left >= self.canvas_width:
            self.car_top_left += -self.canvas_width - self.car_body_width
            self.car_canvas.move(ALL, -self.canvas_width - self.car_body_width, 0)
            self.root.after(self.delay, self.move_car)

    def increase_delay(self, event):
        # Added the if statement below so that the user cannot change the delay when the car is not moving
        if self.car_is_moving:
            self.delay += 10

    def decrease_delay(self, event):
        if self.delay > self.default_delay and self.car_is_moving:
            self.delay -= 10
        # You can just delete this elif statement, I just wanted to print out something to the terminal
        elif self.delay <= self.default_delay and self.car_is_moving:
            print("Delay cannot be lower than default!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CarAnimation()
```

Note that as mentioned in the code you can use 'self.car_canvas.coords()' instead of storing the top left corner. If you have any questions regarding the code, please ask in the comments